# Get 21007 status code by verifying receipt with iTunes URL?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, skproduct

My In-App purchase for Auto-Renewable is working perfectly with the sandbox URL.

```
let verifyReceiptURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
```

But when I am trying to build it with iTunes URL I am getting `21007 status code`.

```
let verifyReceiptURL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
```

My question is, Is it supposed to happen?

Comment: This is expected. That code indicates that a sandbox receipt was sent to the production endpoint. The correct response to receiving that code is to send the receipt to the sandbox endpoint. This will be required during the app review process

Comment: So it will work perfectly when the App will be on App Store. Right? Another question is, is it possible to check the iTunes endpoint on development?

Comment: Yes, but you should not be verifying the receipt directly in your app. You should pass the receipt to your server and have it verify the receipt and pass the response back to your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Right now to the limitation of the server, I do it on the client-side. Have a nice day. :)